# TypeScript Conditional Return errors

Tags: typescript

I have a relatively simple function that should return a string or a number based on what it is given.  I have read over many of the existing issues, and do have function overloads working, but I just want to know why the following errors on all the return lines.

This function should accept a string or number defaultValue, and then return that type.  So if defaultValue is a string, it should return a string.  If defaultValue is a number, it should return a number.

```
export const getMessageAttributes = <T extends string | number = string>(
    attributes: { [key: string]: { Name: string; Value: string } },
    name: string,
    defaultValue?: T,
): T extends string ? string : number => {
    const attribute = attributes[name];

    if (!attribute) {
        if (defaultValue === undefined)
            throw new Error(`MessageAttribute ${name} required but not found`);

        return defaultValue;
    }

    const value = attribute.Value;

    if (typeof defaultValue === 'number') return parseInt(value, 10);

    return value;
};
```

On the `return defaultValue;` line, I get this error:

```
Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'T extends string ? string : number'.
  Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'T extends string ? string : number'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T extends string ? string : number'.ts(2322)
```

On the `return parseInt` line, I get this error:

```
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'T extends string ? string : number'.ts(2322)
```

On the final `return value;` line, I get this error:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T extends string ? string : number'.ts(2322)
```

I am using TypeScript version 3.7.2 if that helps.  As mentioned, I do have this working with type overloads and technically, this might be better solved with 2 separate functions (`getStringMessageAttribute` and `getNumberMessageAttribute`) but really just trying to expand my TypeScript knowledge and understand why it currently fails and if there is a way to fix it.  Thanks!

Comment: Please consider editing the above code to constitute a [mcve] with no dependencies on external types in order to demonstrate your issue.  This is likely a design limitation in TypeScript (see [microsoft/TypeScript#22735](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22735)) and there is an open issue suggesting possible ways to address it (see [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912))

Comment: Thank you, I edited to remove the one external type.  I also did not see that first link you sent over which gave me a way to resolve this, which I will post as an answer.  Still curious if there is a better solution but hopefully this helps if someone else runs into this.

Answer (score 0):

@jcalz provided a link that explained the errors here:
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22735

The relevant part is

> In order for this to work you have to explicitly cast the return
>   values to match the return type annotation because the type checker
>   isn't capable of proving that it is always true:

So, using this I ended up with the following which returns the correct type with no errors:

```
export const getMessageAttributes = <T extends string | number = string>(
    attributes: { [key: string]: { Name: string; Value: string } },
    name: string,
    defaultValue?: T,
): T extends string ? string : number => {
    const attribute = attributes[name];

    if (!attribute) {
        if (defaultValue === undefined)
            throw new Error(`MessageAttribute ${name} required but not found`);

        return (defaultValue as unknown) as T extends string ? string : number;
    }

    const value = attribute.Value;

    if (typeof defaultValue === 'number')
        return (parseInt(value, 10) as unknown) as T extends string
            ? string
            : number;

    return (value as unknown) as T extends string ? string : number;
};
```

Unsure if this is the best approach but it does work so hopefully helps someone else if they run into something similar.

Comment: Anyone know why it's not capable of making the inference? It seems straight forward to me.

Answer (score 0):

Another admittedly more verbose approach using function overloading.

```js
export function getMessageAttributes(attributes: { [key: string]: { Name: string; Value: string } },
    name: string,
    defaultValue?: string): string

export function getMessageAttributes(attributes: { [key: string]: { Name: string; Value: string } },
    name: string,
    defaultValue?: number): number

export function getMessageAttributes<T extends string | number = string>(
    attributes: { [key: string]: { Name: string; Value: string } },
    name: string,
    defaultValue?: T,
) {
    const attribute = attributes[name];

    if (!attribute) {
        if (defaultValue === undefined)
            throw new Error(`MessageAttribute ${name} required but not found`);

        return defaultValue;
    }

    const value = attribute.Value;

    if (typeof defaultValue === 'number') return parseInt(value, 10);

    return value;
};
```